# How to add transparent background color css to layerslider wp

Tags: html, css, wordpress

As you can see from these screenshots: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7xUaY.jpg and https://i.stack.imgur.com/jMENP.jpg I'm using layerslider wp and I'd like to make the background around the text transparent. You can see in the second screenshot that there's a place for custom css. What css should I put in there to make that happen? As always I appreciate the help.

Cheers!

Comment: did you try changing background to transparent?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to find the class or id of that div. Once you know that, you can use the following css:

```
.your-text-div {
    background-color: transparent;
}
```